# An interesting equation of some practical interest.

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

I have encountered a problem in my elec. eng research that I find rather challenging, being a bear of very little brain. The question has been considered under a slightly different aspect here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0607011

My formulation of the problem is as follows: with all quantities real, is it possible to express the smallest positive $x$ s.t.

$e^{ax}-b(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=0$

in closed form? The Lambert W function easily solves the case with one factor $(x-r)$.

Returning to the "quadratic" case, depending on the sign of $b$ one can have 0,1,2 or even three real solutions, the "2+" cases having a clear connection with the two real branches of W (at least in approximation), expressing two solutions "on either side" of $r_1$ (or $r_2$). My specific application constrains $a<0$ and I usually consider $r_1\lt r_2$ with no further restrictions on the sign of either.

My hope is that someone on this list might find the question entertaining in a more general context; perhaps indicate or preclude a standard method of attack. Numerical solutions are straightforward, but I wonder if more physical insight might be achieved otherwise.

Comment: Could you please explain what is a "closed form" (which apparently includes Lambert's function). A convergent power series with
rational coefficients is a closed form or not ?


Comment: Hi Alexandre, apologies for my imprecision. I'm not certain that the Lambert W itself needs to appear in the solution. I don't honestly know whether such a power series constitutes a "closed form" solution: to be really useful, I would like it to include the conditions under which it can converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in a series solution.  After a change of variable we can rewrite the equation in the form
$$ {{\rm e}^{-x}}-b x \left( sx-1 \right) = 0$$
so that for $s=0$ we have a solution at $x = w$ where $w = \text{LambertW}(-1/b)$.
Then we have a series solution in powers of $s$, which should converge for small $|s|$:

$$\eqalign{ x &= w+{\frac {{w}^{2}s}{w+1}}+{\frac {{w}^{3} \left( w+2 \right) ^{2}
{s}^{2}}{2 \left( w+1 \right) ^{3}}}+{\frac {{w}^{4} \left( 2{w}
^{4}+17{w}^{3}+48{w}^{2}+60w+30 \right) {s}^{3}}{6 \left( w+1
 \right) ^{5}}}\cr &+{\frac {{w}^{5} \left( w+2 \right)  \left( 6{w
}^{5}+68{w}^{4}+257{w}^{3}+462{w}^{2}+420w+168 \right) {s}^{4}
}{ 24\left( w+1 \right) ^{7}}}\cr&+{\frac {{w}^{6} \left( 
24{w}^{8}+442{w}^{7}+3172{w}^{6}+12149{w}^{5}+28040{w}^{4}+
40860{w}^{3}+37440{w}^{2}+20160w+5040 \right) {s}^{5}}{ 120 \left( w
+1 \right) ^{9}}}\cr
&+\ldots}
$$

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for that! Did $a$ drop out somewhere, or is it encoded in $s$? Let me try a few numerical examples and see how I get on. You don't happen to know the condition "small |s|" more precisely? In any event, I'm very grateful that this problem was considered worthwhile. Much appreciated!

Comment: In the original equation $e^{ax} - b (x - r_1)(x - r_2) = 0$, take $x = r_1 + X/a$ and you get $e^{a r_1} e^X - \dfrac{b}{a^2} X (X - a(r_2-r_1)$.  

Comment: So the new equation is $e^X - B X (s X - 1)$ where $s = \dfrac{1}{a(r_2-r_1)}$ and $B = e^{-a r_1} \dfrac{b(r_2 - r_1)}{a}$ 

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you again! I had tried a change of variables before, but not quite in this way. What's interesting is that I had tried two similar methods to your power series before, one based on series reversion and the other using the Lagrange Inversion Theorem (and both worked out on paper!). I'm sure these methods are similar to the calculation that develops the power series above, though I didn't have a term $w=W(...)$. As with your solution which I integrated into my model today, I discovered that there are numerical examples that crop up readily that get close to the answer only after

Comment: hundreds of terms. When the $w$ calculated for your power series is a significant fraction of 1.0 (~0.3), the same problem arises (even though $s$ is small ~ 1e-3).

So I can turn this into a more general question: how come the Newton-Raphson iteration (NR) performs so well in these cases? Is it because will involve $exp()$ terms at each step, which in some way contain an infinite series that is only term-wise calculated in the power series and similar approaches?

Answer (score 1):

See [this arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00138), which considers this and similar equations.

Comment: Can you at least briefly describe the article and give its title and author? People should be able to see the main point of an answer and learn something without following any links.