# Solution to $(A+x^2)e^x=B$ with Lambert W function

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, closed-form-expressions

Is it possible to obtain a analytical solution for $(A+x^2)e^x=B$, where we want to solve for $x$ with $A,B$ as constants?

Comment: Sage and Maple can't solve this symbolically

Comment: What about (x - t + exp(x)) exp(x) = a please?

Answer (score 12):

You seek a solution in $x$ of the transcendental equation
$$e^x(x-t_1)(x-t_2)=a.$$
(The coefficients $t_1,t_2$ are real for $A<0$, complex otherwise.) The solution $W(t_1,t_2;a)$ is referred to as the "*quadratic Lambert-W function*". It is
studied in several recent papers:

- [General Relativity and
  Quantum Mechanics: Towards a Generalization of the Lambert W
  Function](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0607011) (2006)
- [On the
  generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in
  theoretical physics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999v2) (2014) [section 4]
- [Some physical applications of generalized Lambert functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01555) (2015)
- [Generalization of Lambert W-function, Bessel polynomials and transcendental equations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00138v2) (2015)

A series expansion is presented in
[Asymptotic series of Generalized Lambert W Function](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262399928_Asymptotic_series_of_Generalized_Lambert_W_function) (see also
this [MO posting](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116562/an-interesting-equation-of-some-practical-interest)).

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this transcendental algebraic equation is indeed a Generalized Lambert W function and there are a number of papers on the latter, not only the pioneering 2006 AAECC paper mentioned here.  See the papers in https://www.researchgate.net/project/Generalized-Lambert-W-function

Granted the second reference, the one by Mezo and Keady claims that the approach used for a particular instance in Physics is 'unsatisfactory' for getting all the solutions but that's an issue of completeness of solutions - not an actual error. Subsequent papers in SIGSAM in that link I just gave, offer more solutions.  E.g. check out the most recent publications by Aude Maignan on the ResearchGate project:

https://www.researchgate.net/project/Generalized-Lambert-W-function

Much work has been done since the 2006 paper.

Comment: The second half of your post might work better as a comment on the other answer; it's more likely to get Carlo Beenakker's attention.

Comment: Thanks but I am new to this forum, I tried to comment on Carlo Beenakker's answer but I was denied permission.  I don't have '50 reputation' yet.

Comment: I removed the offending comment, which referred to this criticsm by Mezo and Keady: _"For a class of parameters the Scott et al. solution does not give back all the solutions and, in other cases, it gives a virtual solution. One might study exactly when the Scott et al. solution works properly."_

Comment: Thank you for the change and clarification.