# Solution to $a=e^t (t-r_1)(t-r_2)$ with Lambert $W$ function, where $r_1, r_2 $ are complex

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, matrices, computability-theory

Lambert $W$ works when $r_1$, and $r_2$ are real. However, I am trying to solve the equation when $r_1$, and $r_2$ are complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This equation cannot be solved in terms of the Lambert $W$ function or any other known functions -- even if a, r1, and r2 are real, let alone complex.

Here is what Mathematica says about this:

[image]

Comment: Lambert W works when r1, and r2 are real.

Comment: @HamedElwarfalli : How does it work then, for real r1 and r2? I believe you are mistaken.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217499/solution-to-ax2ex-b-with-lambert-w-function

Comment: @HamedElwarfalli : Looking at those linked papers, it appears that the function "solving" the equation was just given a name (of a generalized Lambert function), and some properties of such a function have been studied, including a **formal** series representation. However, even the radius of convergence of that representation has not been [determined](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00138v2); see also [p. 17](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (perhaps, the radius of convergence is $0$). Apparently, this is why Mathematica does not consider these developments notable.

Comment: @HamedElwarfalli : And, of course, the genuine Lambert $W$ function does not solve your equation. for real or complex r1 and r2 (unless r1=r2).